# Issue with redirects and PHP variables

Tags: php, html, variables, redirect, meta-tags

So I have the following code:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=/$file\" />";
```

I'm redirecting a user to the location of $file (which has been created before). Unfortunately, the script is redirecting to

```
http://home/[redacted]/public_html/[redacted]/output/ytusgh
```

when, in fact, I want it to be redirected to http://[redacted].co.uk/output/ytusgh

Does anybody know what I can do to make the redirect *work?*

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($file)`?

Comment: string(47) "/home/[redacted]/public_html/[redacted]/output/ytusgh"

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the redirection is done by the browser -- which works with URLs.

So, you have to make sure that you are **using an URL in your `<meta>` tag** ; and not a path to a file.

I don't know how you construct your `$file` variable ; but you'll have to change that portion of code, to make sure that `$file` doesn't point to a file -- but that, instead, it contains the URL you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're passing a local path while u need to pass an absolute path

try

```
$file = preg_replace('path/to/local/folder', '', $file);
$file = $yourdomain . $file;
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;url=/$file\" />";
```